# JQuery .append() only works once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am building a chat application with JQuery and PHP. The PHP writes the chat input to the `data.txt` file and the JQuery is used to append the div where I want the chat to be printed. My output prints the username of the person who sent the chat, however the message is never added to the div. Please help!

JQuery Code:

```
function updateChat() {
    if(!instanse){
        instanse = true;
        /* define AJAX function */
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {'function': 'update','state': state,'file': file},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.text){
                    /* manage data */
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                        alert(data.text[i]);
                        $('#chat-row').append($(""+ data.text[i] +""));
                    }  
                }
                /* manage position of current chat */
                document.getElementById('chat-row').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-row').scrollHeight;
                instanse = false;
                state = data.state;
            }
        });
    }
    else {
    setTimeout(updateChat, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get in `data`?

Comment: `($(""+ data.text[i] +"")` what are the quotes for `($(data.text[i])`

Comment: Where do you set `state` and `file` in this code?

Comment: Did you mean something like `.append($("<div>"+ data.text[i] +"</div>"))`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly `file` is set at the beginning of the JS and `state` is set in the `ajax.php` file. The quotes are there as I discovered that without them nothing gets appended.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Alerting `data.test` will give `<div class='ChatName'>Test</div> ,<div class='ChatMsg'>Testing</div>`.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone This makes it work, however it does not allow me to add a class to the Username <div> or the Message <div>.

Comment: You should do `console.log(data.text[i]);`. What is the console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by replacing this:

```
success: function(data) {
            if(data.text){
                /* manage data */
                for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                    alert(data.text[i]);
                    $('#chat-row').append($(data.text[i]));
                }  
            }
```

with this:

```
success: $('#chat-row').load('data.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

`.append( content [, content ] )`, where `content` is DOM element, text node, array of elements and text nodes, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

I think `$(""+ data.text[i] +"")`  ==  [Object, oblect]

```
function updateChat() {
if(!instanse){
    instanse = true;
    /* define AJAX function */
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {'function': 'update','state': state,'file': file},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.text){
                /* manage data */
                for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                    alert(data.text[i]);
                    $('#chat-row').append($(data.text[i]));
                }  
            }
            /* manage position of current chat */
            document.getElementById('chat-row').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-row').scrollHeight;
            instanse = false;
            state = data.state;
        }
    });
} else {
    setTimeout(updateChat, 1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: It is an [Object, Object], however without the quotes nothing appends.